# Blocks can't contain more than 81 transactions

Tags: private-blockchain, mining, gas-limit, blocks, difficulty

I'm building a private blockchain with Parity clients. For performance testing, I'm submitting many identical transactions. One of the nodes has a GPU miner attached. There are 2 issues I cannot explain and hope to get some help from you:

1. A block never has more than 81 transactions, although gas limit allows for many more. Namely, every transaction consumes exactly 21000 gas, and every full block consumes 1701000 gas, although its gas limit is 8Mgas.
2. Every other block contains zero transactions.

[image: console output]

[image: Block data]

UPDATE: Here are my Ethash parameters:

```
    "Ethash": {
      "params": {
        "minimumDifficulty": "0x10000",
        "difficultyBoundDivisor": "0x800",
        "durationLimit": "0xd",
        "blockReward": {
          "0x0": "0x1bc16d674ec80000"
        },
        "bombDefuseTransition": "0",
        "homesteadTransition": "0x0",
        "eip100bTransition": "0x0"
      }
    }
```

Comment: What are the parameters of your testnet? How do you generate the transactions? Which configuration is used to run parity clients? Which miner are you using? Which parameters do you use with the miner?

Comment: @Ismael Added the engine parameters to the question. Running Parity with default parameters. The miner is installed by another team member, but if there is a relevant parameter, I can ask.

Comment: We use ethminer: `./ethminer -G -SP`